# Count unique dates from a multidimensional list

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.4

I am querying a database for Leads. Leads have a "lead generated date" and a possible "closed" date.

What I would like to do is get a month by month total for leads generated/leads closed per month in the format [MM/YYYY, leads generated, leads closed] for Google Visualization API.

I have my query logic set and currently have a a result similar to:

```
[
["09/2011","09/2011"],
["09/2011","10/2011"],
["10/2011","12/2011"],
...
]
```

I am stuck trying to come up with an efficient way parse this and get the result of:

```
[
["09/2011", 2, 1],
["10/2011", 1, 1],
["12/2011", 0, 1]
]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you should show your models and your query logic, because I don't understand why you are starting off with your dates in nested 2-element lists. This might be easier if you would give yourself a better starting point. **Edit**: Oh is your input list supposed to be `[lead_opened, lead_closed]` for each record?

Comment: Correct, the input list is supposed to be [lead_opened, lead_closed] for each record. I ended up flattening the list and getting unique dates and then created 2 more lists, one with all the generated dates and the other with the closed dates. Then I looped through dates and did leads_assigned_dates.count(date) etc. There has to be a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that beautiful, but this should work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = defaultdict(int)
d2 = defaultdict(int)

data = [["09/2011","09/2011"],["09/2011","10/2011"],["10/2011","12/2011"]]

for d in data:
    d1[d[0]] += 1
    d2[d[1]] += 1

out = []
for key in set(d1.keys()) | set(d2.keys()):
    out.append([key, d1.get(key, 0), d2.get(key, 0)])
```

Comment: You could "beautify" it a bit by using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in your `for` loop ;)